# Why are children in my React.FC undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a column Wrapper that takes in children:

```
const ThreeColumnWrapper: React.FC = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const itemLength = React.Children.count(children);
  const isOdd = IsOdd(itemLength);
  const { isCompact } = MediaQuery();
  return (
    <Base>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            {isCompact && isOdd && index === 0 ? (
              <Full>{child}</Full>
            ) : (
              <ThreeByTwo>{child}</ThreeByTwo>
            )}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </Base>
  );
};
```

I mapp it like so:

```
const columnComponentMap = {
  3: ThreeColumnWrapper
};
```

and in my grid i call it::

```
const CategoryGrid: React.FC<PropType> = (props) => {
  const { categories, columns } = props;

  const Component = columnComponentMap[columns];

  return (
    <Component>
      {categories.map((category, index) => {
        <ImageCard
          key={index}
          imageURL={category.image}
          linkURL={category.url}
          title={category.title}
          aspectRatio="1_1"
        />;
      })}
    </Component>
  );
};
```

In my categories data I have 7 items but when they come to my Wrapper I only get undefined, why?

Image of the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <Component>
      {categories.map((category, index) => {
        // Missing return here
        return <ImageCard
          key={index}
          imageURL={category.image}
          linkURL={category.url}
          title={category.title}
          aspectRatio="1_1"
        />;
      })}
    </Component>
```

You missed a return.

It's an easy error to make with `.map()` one of the reason why I favor implicit returns when I only have a single instruction

Comment: Oh lord, You will not belive the time I spent on this because I wrote {} instead of ().
Cheers

Comment: @CodingLittle haha it happens to the best of us, don't hesitate to mark your quesiton as resolved if that was indeed your issue